# Use function after the previous function is done

Tags: javascript

Is there the way to use the other function after the first function is done working?

The first function will be used when the number is being called. 
And it will loop thru and play the audio.

```
function sound() {  

number2 = get.num; // '1002', '2003' etc.
sNumber = number2.toString();
output = [];
delay = 2000;

callon = new Audio('logo/call.wav');
callon.play();

for ( i = 0, len = sNumber.length; i < len; i ++) {

    output.push(+sNumber.charAt(i));
    console.log(output);
        switch (output[i])
        {
        case 0:
        audio0 = new Audio('logo/Q0.wav');
        // audio0.play();
        setTimeout(function(){audio0.play();},delay);
        console.log(output[i]);
        break;
        case 1:
        console.log('1');
        audio1 = new Audio('logo/Q1.wav');
        // audio0.play();
        setTimeout(function(){audio1.play();},delay);
        break;
        case 2:
        audio2 = new Audio('logo/Q2.wav');
        // audio0.play();
        console.log(output[i]);
        setTimeout(function(){audio2.play();},delay);
        break;
        case 3:
        console.log('3');
        audio3 = new Audio('logo/Q3.wav');
        // audio0.play();
        setTimeout(function(){audio3.play();},delay);
        break;
            }
        delay = delay + 1100;
        }service();
}
```

The second function mean to play another sound when the first function is done working.

```
function service() {
var sService = get.service;

if( sService == '2'){
    console.log('got in!');
    call2 = new Audio('logo/ch02.wav');
    call2.play();
}}
```

Comment: It looks like you don't call `service()` anywhere in your parent function. I'd suggest adding it as a callback inside of the timeout, since your using timeout you'll have to be careful with the delay time.

Comment: @Callat Yes, because i don't know that function callback is even exist. Thank you so much but can you show me somehow to do this ?